# Twitter Bootstrap Form Field Format

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Labels are not in aligned with the fields.
I want to make sure that labels be wrapped elegantly if exceeds the column width. 
Here is complete [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjuQg/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row row-padded">
        <strong>Question: </strong><p>Are you 18 years old?</p>
        <strong>Answer:</strong>
        <div class="radio-inline">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-inline">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios1" id="optionsRadios2" value="option1">No</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 childFields">
            <p class="">Give full details here: </p>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields">
                <label>Nature of Condition</label>
                <input type="text" name="city"/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields">
                <label>Dates and Duration</label>
                <input type="text" name="city"/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields">
                <label>Name Of Doctor</label>
                <input type="text" name="city"/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields">
                <label>Name of Hospital</label>
                <input type="text" name="city"/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 colChildFields">
                <label>Address of Hospital</label>
                <input type="text" name="city"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood you right, but if [that](http://jsfiddle.net/cjuQg/3/)'s what you're looking for, you should just add this to the CSS:

```
.col-md-6 label {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I want label and input field in a single row.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that. I am looking label and input field in a single row. Your example has label and field on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an horizontal form, you'll have to use a container div with class `form-group` and add a class `control-label` to the label, `form-control` to the input, with a structure like this :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Replace (in classes) `-lg-` by `-xs-` and it will be responsive and self managed if the label is longer.

See example with my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGuJV/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have gone through Bootstrap documentation. Looking for a solution specific to my problem that's why I have shared the fiddle.

Comment: When you will use it with my example the you will understand. Here I have given a small piece of a big form. I can' treat it as a separate form. It messes up with the whole form layout.